# "unknown type name 'size_t'" error from included .cpp file, but removed when included file name changed to .h file. Why?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

It's like the question title.
I was updating my program for arm64 machine. A file that was included was changed from "args.cpp" to "args.h". Inside the include file type `size_t` was being used(previously too). Now the compiler (aarch64-none-linux-gnu- ) complains with "unknown type name 'size_t'" error. If I change the included file name just to args.cpp, the errors are gone. Why is thing happening? and How can I use `args.h` as the included file name?

Comment: Don't just describe the problem in words as that is imprecise and unclear. Please show code as a [mre].

Comment: Don't `#include` cpp files, they are not intended for that.

Comment: We can't answer the question if you don't post the relevant parts of the source. `#include <stddef.h>` will solve the problem, but your file structure seems problematic and broken so this is likely just the top of the iceberg.

Comment: The problem was in the Makefile. sorry.

Comment: I'll leave this question here because this is still a case that a programmer can meet with makefile problem and someone can get help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was not in the code. In my Makefile, I mistakenly put $^ instead of $< as below.

```
%: %.c include/*.h
    $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc -g -fmax-errors=5 -DQEMU -I$(AXPUDIR) -I$(INCDIR) $^ -o $@
```

So the make tried to compile the header file (which I put as prerequisite, to make it recompiled when I change the header file) which errors out because by itself the header file didn't have definition fo size_t.  So I changed $^ to $< and the problem is gone. I feel sorry for misleading..

Answer (score 0):

`#include <stddef.h>` for `size_t` (C)

`#include <cstddef>` for `std::size_t` (C++)

`cstddef` also defines `size_t` in the global namespace, although it is not guaranteed by the C++ standard.

Comment: putting #include <stddef.h> in the args.h file solved it. But I can't understand it.  The main file has #include <stdlib.h> which includes the stddef.h.